# Java Hadoop-lzo Found interface but class was expected LzoTextInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, ant, hadoop-lzo

I'm trying to use the [Hadoop-LZO](https://github.com/toddlipcon/hadoop-lzo) package (built using the steps [here](http://www.devops-blog.net/hadoop/compiling-and-installing-hadoop-lzo-compression-support-module)). Seems like everything worked successfully as I was able to convert my lzo files to indexed files via (this returns `big_file.lzo.index` as expected):

```
hadoop jar /path/to/your/hadoop-lzo.jar com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoIndexer big_file.lzo
```

Then I go to use these files in my mapreduce jobs (with `big_file.lzo.index` as the input):

```
import com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat;
....
Job jobConverter = new Job(conf, "conversion");
jobConverter.setJar("JsonConverter.jar");
jobConverter.setInputFormatClass(LzoTextInputFormat.class);
....
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.listStatus(LzoTextInputFormat.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:389)
    at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.getSplits(LzoTextInputFormat.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.wwbp.JsonConverter.run(JsonConverter.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.wwbp.JsonConverter.main(JsonConverter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I've seen other questions answering this and they say to re-build against Hadoop v2. So I redownloaded everything fro Github and ran

```
% hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.0-mapr-1607
Compiled by root on 2016-07-18T07:56Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
This command was run using /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0-mapr-1607.jar

% ant clean compile-native tar -Dhadoopversion=27
....
tar:
  [tar] Building tar: ../jars/hadoop-lzo/build/hadoop-lzo-0.4.15.tar.gz

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15 seconds
```

When building my paths are as follows:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=../jars/lzo-2.09/include
LIBRARY_PATH=../jars/lzo-2.09/lib
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong. How do I get `ant` to see Hadoop v2?

**Edit 1**: Possibly of note: when I run both my mapreduce job (calling `LzoTextInputFormat.class`) and the lzo converter (on `big_file.lzo`) my classpath is as follows

```
CLASS_PATH=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/etc/hadoop:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/opt/mapr/lib/kvstore*.jar:/opt/mapr/lib/libprotodefs*.jar:/opt/mapr/lib/baseutils*.jar:/opt/mapr/lib/maprutil*.jar:/opt/mapr/lib/json-20080701.jar:/opt/mapr/lib/flexjson-2.1.jar:/jars/hadoop-lzo-0.4.15/hadoop-lzo-0.4.15.jar
```

**Edit 2**: If I index the lzo file as follows (i.e. try to index via a mapreduce job with `DistributedLzoIndexer` instead of `LzoIndexer`) I get a similar error:

```
> hadoop jar /path/to/your/hadoop-lzo.jar com.hadoop.compression.lzo.DistributedLzoIndexer big_file.lzo
16/12/09 13:06:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/12/09 13:06:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1472572940387_0370_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why the above isn't working so I started from scratch using this repo:

https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo

instead of the one linked above and used maven to build instead of ant (using all of the same settings as above).